# I want to write DXF attributes to a DXF file from VB

Tags: vb.net, dxf

So I wrote a massive plugin for Rhino5. I now need it to somehow talk to sigmanest. The best way I can do that is string tags.

Meaning, I DXF a part with the correct part information in text boxes next to the part. But my job does not want that (I have no idea why)

The next thing I can do is embed attributes into the DXF. My plan is to export the part, then write to the DXF file new attributes.

Has anyone done such a thing? I've done some pretty heavy googling, but couldn't find any topics on just writing new attributes to a DXF.

A quick and dirty sample code would be great if you have done this, or link to the information.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you want to attach the DXF entity ATTRIB to some block references, or do you want attaching extended data to some common DXF entities?

Comment: That's the trick, We are using rhino. They don't use blocks with attributes. Sigmanest looks for attribute tags that you can define. Like PARTNUMBER:
It looks for that attribute, and anything after the : it gets. I need to somehow instert those into the dxf that I made.
I did find this https://netdxf.codeplex.com/
Testing with it today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only answering for googles sake...

netDXF is a C# library that reads and writes dxf files and is freely available.

To insert a custom attribute, do the following

```
Dim aTT= New AttributeDefinition(AttributeNameString)
aTT.Flags = AttributeFlags.Hidden
block.AttributeDefinitions.Add(aTT)
block.AttributeDefinitions(AttributeNameString).Value = VaribleorString
```